# Opencart 3 redirect store-domain.com/catalog to home page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart, opencart-3

When a user tries to open a page in *Opencart 3* `www.store-domain.com/catalog` it displays a

> Forbidden access error page

How can I have it redirect to a home page or other custom page?